# PixiJS on Meteor with router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, pixi.js, flow-router

I am working on a project using Meteor with Pixi.js, 
and I'm facing a very strange problem when I try to use a router
(I tried both IronRouter and FlowRouter), and a pixi canvas.

The canvas is built, but i cant render any sprite on it.
This happen only when i use a route parameter, such as '/game/:id'

This is working except when i use a route parameter, such as '/game/:id'
More, if i dont use route parameter,
Sprite is showing up when i access '/game'
Sprite doesn't show up when i access '/game/

Here is a minimal error code on a meteor app :

Any Router definition :

```
Router.route('/room/:_id', {
    action: function() {
        this.render('game');
    }
});
```

A basic template :
Html :

```
<template name="game"></template>
```

Js :

```
Template.game.onRendered(function () {
PIXI.loader.add("assets/mario.png")
    .load(() => {
        let app = new PIXI.Application();
        document.body.appendChild(app.view);
        let mario = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources["assets/mario.png"].texture);
        mario.position.set(5, 5);
        mario.width = 48;
        mario.height = 48;
        app.stage.addChild(mario);
        app.render();
    });
});
```

The pixi canvas will show up but mario sprite doesn't.

Comment: Is there a reason you're appending the canvas to body and not to the template? Blaze mounts on the body by default, which is probably wiping away your canvas as a result

Comment: Try putting a container div inside your game template and appending your canvas to that

Comment: I actually append the canvas to a div in the template, and got the same error.
I did use document.body on my post, cause i am not sure pixi users will be aware of blaze works, and i wanted to respect their basic example.